Error: Cannot find module 'node:path' while running "npm -v" or "npm --version"
My project depends on Node v10.24 and npm v6.9 as it's a very old project.
I installed node v10.24 and when I run node -v it's returning 10.24 which is expected
Now when I want to verify npm version using npm -v or npm --version i am getting below error.

Could you please help me on this? I have installed multiple times and tried to restart the system as well, but still stuck here.

I suspect you have a newer version of npm which isn't compatible with node v10. You can check the file C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json to see which version of npm is actually installed.

You could also install the spécific version npm install npm@6.9 -g

@AngelRafael as npm -v throwing error, so we can't run npm install command as well, It'll throw same error

@JSONDerulo , the location which you mentioned I can't find the package.json file in that folder, Should I delete npm and and npm-cache folder and try to re-install the node?

Sorry it was the wrong path, try C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\package.json

Hey @JSONDerulo , Thanks for your help, yes you are correct it was some different version. To fix this issue, I just delete npm and npm-cache folders form C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming location, and re-installed the node, now it's working fine, I am able to see the npm version.

@SangramBadi you're right, my bad. You can try to manually change the path of the environment variable named NODEJS_DIR to the location of your node v10.24 installation.

Hey @AngelRafael Thanks for your help, I just fixed this issue

node: is only supported from Node 12.30/14.13.1 (ESM import) or 14.18/16 (CJS require).

Managing different version of node and npm kills
